# Start doxygen list at zero

Tags: list, markdown, doxygen

I am using doxygen and would like to create a zero-based list

I have tried:

```
<ol start="0"> ... </ol>
```

and

```
0. 0-item
1. 1-item ...
```

with no luck... is there another way I can try?

Update: just noticed the first method works in the HTML output, but it is the LaTeX I am concerned with, and that doesnt work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a zero numbered list, you could try

```
Zero list
\zerolist
\zeroitem{Zero}
\zeroitem{One}
\zeroitem{Two}
\endzerolist
```

in combination with the following alias definitions in the config file:

```
ALIASES                = zerolist="\latexonly\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{-1}\endlatexonly\htmlonly<ol start=\"0\">\endhtmlonly" \
                         zeroitem{1}="\latexonly\item \1\endlatexonly\htmlonly<li>\1</li>\endhtmlonly" \
                         endzerolist="\latexonly\end{enumerate}\endlatexonly\htmlonly</ol>\endhtmlonly"
```

which works for the HTML and the LaTeX output.